# How to center multiple rows in a column using Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, laravel, bootstrap-4

I have a col div with 3 row divs and I want to place them on the center of the col div, as you can see on the picture, the row divs are on the left side of the col div, and I don't know how to put them on the center of the col div.

[image]

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="col text-center">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="tantargyselectdiv" class="col-sm-5">
      <select name="tantargyselect" id="tantargyselect">
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5 text-center">
      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Mehet</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div id="tanarselectdiv" class="col-sm-5">
      <select name="tanarselect" id="tanarselect">
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5 text-center">
      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Mehet</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <form action="{{URL::to('statisztikaBetoltFelev')}}" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{!! csrf_token() !!}">
      <div id="felevselectdiv" class="col-sm-5 text-center">
        <select name="felevselect" id="felevselect">
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-5 text-center">
        <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Mehet</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

I know it looks terrible for professional web developers, but I'm not an expert in styling, please help me if you can.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: have you tried `<div class="row mx-auto">`

Comment: I have removed the unnecessary code

Comment: Yes, I tried mx-auto, but it didn't help

Comment: can you try `justify-content-md-center` instead of `mx-auto`

Comment: I tried justify-content-md-center too, but nothing changes unfortunately

Comment: you have 2 option, first one add `justify-content-center` class to each of your rows. second one give `max-width: 900px;` and `margin: 0 auto` to your col

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As many users said in the comment section, `justify-content-center` will work but no one comes with an answer, so I do it.

See the snippet below that helps you to understand.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="col text-center">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div id="tantargyselectdiv" class="col-sm-5">
      <select name="tantargyselect" id="tantargyselect">
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5 text-center">
      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Mehet</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div id="tanarselectdiv" class="col-sm-5">
      <select name="tanarselect" id="tanarselect">
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5 text-center">
      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Mehet</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <form action="{{URL::to('statisztikaBetoltFelev')}}" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{!! csrf_token() !!}">
      <div id="felevselectdiv" class="col-sm-5 text-center">
        <select name="felevselect" id="felevselect">
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-5 text-center">
        <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Mehet</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```